# В QT на ubuntu не появляется окно для выбора цвета или файла

Tags: qt, ubuntu

При нажатии на кнопку основное окно темнеет , а второе не появляется

```
void MainWindow::on_file_clicked() {
  QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Choose File"),
                                                  "/home", tr("OBJ (*.obj)"));
}
```

Библиотеку подключаю `#include <QFileDialog>` Версия Qt -6
Такая проблема только на ubuntu на других системах данный код нормально отрабатывает

Comment: Какая версия Qt, Ubuntu? У меня под 20.04 тоже есть проблемы с диалогами вида getOpenFileName. Как минимум, все тормозит очень сильно.

Comment: Иногда даже падает. Например, при попытке несколько раз вызвать `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`. Причем падают и сторонние приложения - с Octave такое случалось неоднократно.